# Volley POST Request with headers and raw json body

Tags: android, authentication, post, android-volley, postman

I am trying to make Post request from Android App that takes username and password in request body with content-type application/json in headers.

I tried changing content-type and how i send username passoword in body, but still no luck

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button Login;
    private EditText loginEmail, loginPassword;

    String URL = "https://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        loginPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        Login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("username", loginEmail.getText().toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            jsonObject.put("password", loginPassword.getText().toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final String requestBody = jsonObject.toString();


        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LandingPage.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                        if (error instanceof ServerError && response != null) {
                            try {
                                String res = new String(response.data,
                                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
                                // Now you can use any deserializer to make sense of data
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.i("MainActivity", res);
                                //use this json as you want
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                                // Couldn't properly decode data to string
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (JSONException e2) {
                                // returned data is not JSONObject?
                                e2.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })

                {
                    @Override
                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                        try {
                            return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

                        return params;
                    }

                };
                RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                rQueue.add(request);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Post Request from Postman works perfectly fine but it throws Error 400 with Volley.
Below is the error I get in console
"errorSummary":"Bad request.  Accept and/or Content-Type headers likely do not match supported values."

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try using a custom request and extending `Request<JSONObject>` instead of using `StringRequest`. For my case it works this way.

Comment: @MaximilianSpeicher can you provide a sample code? I am pretty new to android

Comment: Sure just give me a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom request and extending `Request<JSONObject>`:

**`CustomRequest` class:**

```
public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {
    private final Map<String, String> mHeaders;
    private final JSONObject mBody;
    private final Response.Listener<JSONObject> mResponseListener;

    public CustomRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> headers, JSONObject body, Response.Listener<JSONObject> responseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mHeaders = headers;
        this.mBody = body;
        this.mResponseListener = responseListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return mHeaders != null ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        return mBody != null ? mBody.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")) : super.getBody();
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        mResponseListener.onResponse(response);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
String url = "https://localhost:8080/api/v1/auth";


Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("username", loginEmail.getText().toString());
    jsonObject.put("password", loginPassword.getText().toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

CustomRequest customRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, headers, jsonObject, response -> {
    // put your reponse listener code here
}, error -> {
    // put your error listener code here
});

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
queue.add(customRequest);
```

Comment: I Still get Error 400. Please look at the Postman screenshots in question to see if you can find something that needs to be changed.

Comment: @JanakSoni I've forgot to add the `parseNetworkResponse` function. You can check the edit and check if it works now. If it doesn´t work, did you check if you get the right username and password from your `EditText` and is the API url available from your test device if you are using localhost?

Comment: I added parseNetworkResponse in CustomRequest. Yes, I am logging both username and password.They are correct.

Comment: Did you just add `parseNetworkResponse` or implemented in the way that I' ve edited it?

Comment: First I just generated empty one and now I Added the way you have implemented.

Comment: I´m sorry. I had an application too much in `getBodyContentType`. Please check if you have the current correct version or if you copied my mistake.

Comment: I copied your typo. corrected it. But still no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198610/discussion-between-maximilian-speicher-and-janak-soni).